# iphone 4s - UIImage CGImage image dimensions

Tags: ios, uiimage, size, cgimage

I have a crash which only occurs on 4S (not on 3GS). I am doubting its because of @2x. Basically I get raw bytes of image and manipulate. Here's the question I have.

I load a image as mentioned in the sample code below. At the end, uiWidth should be 2000 and cgwidth should be 2000. Correct? (Would it still be true if image is loaded from camera rolls? Or its autoscaling and uiWidth will be 4000?)

```
//test.jpg is 2000x 1500 pixels.
NSString *fileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"jpg"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fileName];

int uiWidth = image.size.width;

CGImageRef cgimg = image.CGImage;

int cgWidth = CGImageGetWidth(cgimg);
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Xcode will handle @2x automagically. No need to set double size in codes.

Answer (score 13):

The `size` reported by `UIImage` is in points, not pixels. You need to take into account the `scale` property of `UIImage`.

In other words, if `test.jpg` is 1000x1000 then `UIImage.size` will report 1000x1000. If `test@2x.png` is 2000x2000 then `UIImage.size` will also report 1000x1000. But in the 2nd case, `UIImage.scale` will report 2.

`CGImageGetWidth` reports its width in pixels, not points.

Comment: This means, if I do not take scale into factor then UIImage.size and CGImageGetWidth should be one and same. Right?

Comment: No, the opposite. To convert UIImage points into pixels, you need to multiply by scale.