# Resizing UIImage to pre-defined pixel dimension

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have a simple method that I'm using to resize images. I need to create 2200 x 2200 px images and upload them to a server. I have a working solution but I it doesn't works properly. I think there's something wrong where I set the size for the image because the result is bigger then 10 MB.

```
- (void) uploadImage {

 NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([self resizeImage:self.uploadImg.image reSize:CGSizeMake(2200, 2200)], 1.0);
 ...

}

- (UIImage*)resizeImage:(UIImage*)aImage reSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, YES, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    [aImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Is it a right implementation? The `CGSizeMake(2200, 2200)` is equal to 2200x2200 pixel? If yes, what indicates the 10MB+ file size? It shouldn't be bigger then 1-2MB.

Comment: The size is in points, not pixels. On a retina device the image will be 4400x4400 (on an iPhone 6+ it will be 6600x6600).

Comment: @rmaddy Is it possible to convert it to pixels? I don't wanna create different logic for every device.

Comment: see rmaddy's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13132040/499581

Comment: Another option, if you want a fixed number of pixels and don't care about the scale, pass `1.0` for the `scale` parameter instead of `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale`.